# How do I start the Firebase Storage Emulator with production bucket data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using the Firebase Emulator to run all Firebase services. I have managed to run the emulator with a backup of my Firestore data by running:

`firebase emulators:start --import ./my-directory`

... but I can't find a way to do the same with my Storage data.

Answer (score 2):

**Export**

You can export data using gsutil.

gsutil -m cp -R gs://$STORAGE_BUCKET $OUT_DIR

This creates the directory specified by $OUT_DIR and downloads all the content of your bucket $STORAGE_BUCKET

**Import**

For importing to the emulator, you can use the REST api.

First, see which is the Storage emulator endpoint:

[image]

You can upload files with `PUT`. The endpoint URL is `http://$END_POINT/v0/b/$STORAGE_BUCKET/o/$DEST_ENCODED`. And the file must be passed on the body as data binary.

This is the curl sentence:

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @./$FILE http://$END_POINT/v0/b/$STORAGE_BUCKET/o/$DEST_ENCODED
```

For exemple, if your storage bucket has the name `my_bucket.appspot.com` and you want to upload the file *photo.png* on the root, the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:19199/v0/b/my_bucket.appspot.com/o/photo.png`.

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @./photo.png http://127.0.0.1:19199/v0/b/my_bucket.appspot.com/o/photo.png
```

If the file to upload must be inside a directory, the slash separation must be encoded with `%2F`. For example, for uploading the file *photo.png* to *user/48329884/photo.png*, the URL must be: `http://127.0.0.1:19199/v0/b/my_bucket.appspot.com/o/user%2F48329884%2Fphoto.png`.

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @./photo.png http://127.0.0.1:19199/v0/b/my_bucket.appspot.com/o/user%2F48329884%2Fphoto.png
```

The upload file is always tagged with the content type `application/octet-stream`. Changing the content type on header petition doesn't do any effect.

To change the content type, you must use the same endpoint but with the `PATCH` verb, and passing a file representing the metadata to change.

```
curl -X PATCH --data-binary @./metadata_import.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:19199/v0/b/$STORAGE_BUCKET/o/$DEST_ENCODED
```

The metadata json file must be like this:

```
{
  "contentType": $CONTENT_TYPE
}
```

For example, to change the content type to `image/png` to the previous example:

*metada_import.json* file must contain:

```
{
  "contentType": "image/png"
}
```

and the URL must be:

```
curl -X PATCH --data-binary @./metadata_import.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:19199/v0/b/my_bucket.appspot.com/o/user%2F48329884%2Fphoto.png
```

**Bash files for exporting and importing**

I've created two bash files for exporting from any environment and importing to emulator.

If prefer clone the repository: https://github.com/dumabg/storage_export_import_emulator

**storage_export.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
Red='\033[1;31m'
White='\033[1;37m'
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    printf "${Red}Error parameters: ${White}$0 <storage bucket> <out dir>\n"
    echo "storage bucket without .appspot.com"
    echo "out dir default to out"
    exit 1
fi
if [ -z $2 ]; then
    OUT="out"
else
    OUT=$2
fi
echo $OUT
gsutil -m cp -R gs://$1.appspot.com $OUT
```

**storage_import.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
Red='\033[1;31m'
White='\033[1;37m'
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    printf "${Red}Error parameters: ${White}$0 <storage bucket> <dir>\n"
    echo "storage bucket without .appspot.com"
    exit 1
fi
export STORAGE_BUCKET=$1
export SRC_DIR=$2
import_file() {
    FILE=$1
    DEST=${FILE/$SRC_DIR/}
    DEST_ENCODED=${DEST////%2F}
    curl -X PUT --data-binary @./$FILE http://127.0.0.1:19199/v0/b/$STORAGE_BUCKET.appspot.com/o/$DEST_ENCODED
    curl -X PATCH --data-binary @./metadata_import.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:19199/v0/b/$STORAGE_BUCKET.appspot.com/o/$DEST_ENCODED
    return 0
}
export -f import_file

find $2 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'import_file "{}"'
```

**metada_import.json**

```
{
  "contentType": "image/jpeg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has an option to do import and export, while Firebase storage don't have this feature yet (storage uses upload and download). Currently, there's no native way to import Google Cloud Storage data in the Storage Emulator.

Additionally, you can study how the emulator register the object by uploading sample files within the emulator and then running the export, you will see that the emulator will require 1 object and 1 JSON file that contains it's metadata.  For now, it'll be up to you to download the objects from your production bucket along with a separate JSON file containing its metadata and then structure it for import.

There's also an [opened issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3802) for this in github that you can monitor as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although @RJC's answer is correct, I want to share what I did.

You can add the option `--export-on-exit` when starting the emulator, and it will export the state of the local Firebase instance to a folder of your choice. So I downloaded all my data from the real Firebase project, uploaded everything with the Emulator, then killed the emulator, everything (including storage) got exported and now I start it with the `--import` option using the same folder where I exported everything.

This was not very awful since I didn't that much stuff in my storage.