# How to keep/re-create object metadata during gsutil cp on storage bucket

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I would like to sync all of the files in my Google Cloud Storage bucket with the exported files in my Firebase Storage Emulator.

1. I downloaded all of my cloud files using `gsutil` to my local machine.
2. I used BeyondCompare to move all of the new files to the '..**/storage_export/blobs/** directory.
3. How do I update/create the JSON metadata in '..**/storage_export/metadata**' to reflect these new files and make them available when I run the emulator and import them in?

Edit:

The `gsutil` [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#copying-in-the-cloud-and-metadata-preservation) mention the following:

> when you download data from the cloud, it ends up in a file with no associated metadata, unless you have some way to keep or re-create that metadata.

How would one *"keep"* or *"re-create"* that metadata during a `gsutil cp` download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gsutil or the SDK to get each [object's metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#view) and then write it down to a JSON file however, there's currently no native way to import Google Cloud Storage data in the Storage Emulator. But as I stated in my answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69490218/16531380), you can study how the emulator register the object by uploading sample files within the emulator and then running the export, you will see that the emulator will require 1 object and 1 JSON file that contains it's metadata.

Lastly, you can add the option `--export-on-exit` when starting the emulator, Downloaded all data from the real Firebase project, uploaded everything with the Emulator, then kill the emulator; as stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507139/16531380).

**Note**: This is not a documented feature! Firebase doesn't expose the concept of download tokens in its public SDKs or APIs, so manipulating tokens this way feels a bit "hacky". For your further reference, check this [post](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens).